# Rails Javascript Database Doubt

Tags: javascript, database, ruby-on-rails-3, slide

I am trying to display a set of images at certain time intervals in my rails application. Now i am using javascript for this and taking the timings from the user for the time between each slide to be displayed. Now for that i am using the setTimeout function of javascript in which i am trying to fetch the time from the database,ie, my table named slides.

This is my code snippet for preloading images

```
var preloaded = new Array();


for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    preloaded[x]     = new Image();
    preloaded[x].src = "/images/pausch/img"+x+".gif";
}
```

This is my snippet of the image changing function

```
    function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return;
document.images.slide.src=eval("preloaded["+step+"].src");
if (step<10)
step++;
else
step=0 ;
<% @slides.each do |slide| %>
setTimeout("slideit()",'<%= slide.time.to_i %>')

    <% end %>
}
```

However the images are changing are some random times and not according to the time stored. Can anyone suggest whats wrong?

Comment: the variable step is global with value step=0. Forgot to put that.Sorry.

Comment: Can you show an example of the generated `setTimeout()` lines that the client will see? I suspect you might be having some timeout time conflicts - [this link](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) may help.

Comment: Well, basically it is storing the last entry made in the table in the "time" column. if i had 4 entries as 1,2,3 and 4, by default it stores only 4. Is there some way to generate each of the entry. I was thinking of storing all entries of the table in an array and then run the setTimeout function in a for loop...which makes me think, i want to give different intervals between each image displaying, is this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `setTimeout()` call from inside the function, and put a call to (say) `setInterval(slideit,1000)` somewhere outside the function:

```
    ....
    document.images.slide.src = preloaded[step].src; 

    if (step<10) step++;
    else step=0;
}
setInterval(slideit,1000);
```

This will cause `slideit()` to be called every 1000 miliseconds, rather than assigning multiple timeouts each time the function is called.

Note I also removed the `eval()` call and some extra quotes from your `preloaded[step].src` line - It won't affect the timeout stuff, but you shouldn't need eval here because the contents of the array is just a string (and for security reasons it's generally good to avoid using `eval()` if you can).

**Edit:** Just saw that you want different timeouts for each image. I would do this with a single call to setTimeout():

```
    ....
    document.images.slide.src = preloaded[step].src; 

    setTimeout(slideit,timeouts[step]);

    if (step<10) step++;
    else step=0;
}
```

For this solution, you'll want to initialise an array called `timeouts` where each entry `timeouts[x]` contains the number of miliseconds to display image `x`.